# Error calculando suma con PHP y MySQL y luego insertarla en otra tabla

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Así envío el formulario con JS AJAX a PHP:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  formSubmit()
})

function formSubmit(){

  $('#formComi').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    var idusuario = $('#idusuario').val()
    var desde = $('#fechadesde').val()
    var hasta = $('#fechahasta').val()

    var data = 'idusuario='+idusuario+'&fechadesde='+desde+'&fechahasta='+hasta;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'phps/procesarcomisiones.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: data,
      beforeSend: function(){
        console.log('enviando datos')
      },
      success: function(resp){
        console.log('resp')
      }
    })

  })
```

Aquí está lo que proceso en la consulta MySQL en PHP:

```
<?php
require ('conexion.php');

$vendedor = $_POST["idusuario"];
$desde = $_POST["fechadesde"];
$hasta = $_POST["fechahasta"];

$query = "SELECT * from venta where idusuario = '$vendedor' AND (fecha BETWEEN '$desde' AND '$hasta');";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($query);

$suma=0;
while ($sumar=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    $suma=$suma+$sumar["total"]*0.015;
}

$comision = "INSERT INTO comision (idusuario, fecha_comision, total_comision, desde, hasta)
VALUES ('$vendedor', CURDATE(), '$suma', ' $desde'.''$hasta' )";

if ($mysqli->query($comision) === TRUE){
    echo "registro guardado";
}else {
    echo "error al guardar";
}
?>
```

Comment: Por favor, añade información adicional a la pregunta: ¿Qué es lo que estás intentando hacer? ¿Cómo no está funcionando? ¿Recibes algún mensaje de error? Te recomiendo que te pases por el Centro de Ayuda y leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Aparte de eso, el código que compartes presenta problemas de seguridad y es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. En lugar de generar sentencias SQL concatenando texto dinámicamente, deberías usar sentencias preparadas/parametrizadas.

Comment: Veo la apuesta de @AlvaroMontoro y subo a que la suma podrías haberla hecho en la misma consulta SQL: `SELECT SUM(total) * 0.015 suma_total FROM venta WHERE idusuario = ? AND (fecha BETWEEN ? AND ?)`. Deberías haber dicho que la consulta SQL te devuelve un "error al guardar" debido a un error de sintaxis.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error de sintaxis en la consulta SQL que usas para insertar los datos en la tabla donde pones `' $desde'.''$hasta'`. Quizá debería poner `'$desde', '$hasta'`, pero he preferido mostrarte cómo se hace de manera correcta.

Usar consultas preparadas supone agregar un poco más de código, pero te facilita la lectura del código, su depuración y evita ataques de inyección SQL.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacer tu tarea usando consultas preparadas (más abajo te sugiero unos cambios en el código JavaScript):

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');

$consulta = $mysqli->prepare("
    SELECT
        SUM(total) * 0.015 suma_total
    FROM venta
    WHERE
        idusuario = ?
        AND fecha BETWEEN ? AND ?
");
if ($consulta === false) {
    die('Error en la consulta');
}
/* Cargamos los datos y ejecutamos la consulta */
$consulta->bind_param("i", $_POST["idusuario"]);
$consulta->bind_param("s", $_POST["fechadesde"]);
$consulta->bind_param("s", $_POST["fechahasta"]);
if ($consulta->execute() === false) {
    die($consulta->error);
}
/* Obtenemos el resultado y obtenemos el primer registro con fetch_assoc */
$resultado = $consulta->get_result();
if ($resultado === false) {
    die("Error al obtener el resultado: ". $consulta->errno);
}
$datos = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
if ($datos === false) {
    die("¿No hay datos? (!)");
}
$suma = $datos['suma_total'];
/* Preparamos la consulta de introducción de datos */
$consulta = $mysqli->query("
    INSERT INTO comision (
        idusuario,
        fecha_comision,
        total_comision,
        desde,
        hasta
    ) VALUES (
        ?,
        CURDATE(),
        ?,
        ?,
        ?
    )
");
/* Cargamos los datos y ejecutamos la consulta */
$consulta->bind_param("i", $_POST["idusuario"]);
$consulta->bind_param("i", $suma);
$consulta->bind_param("s", $_POST["fechadesde"]);
$consulta->bind_param("s", $_POST["fechahasta"]);
if ($consulta->execute() === false) {
    die($consulta->error);
}
echo "registro guardado";
```

Te sugiero los siguientes cambios en tu código JavaScript:

- Usar SIEMPRE el indicador de fin de sentencia `;`.
- Si ya has definido una función llamada `formSubmit` úsala como parámetro de `ready` y no crees una función para llamar a una función.
- Es mejor enviar datos en `json` al PHP que montar una cadena que podría sufrir problemas en la interpretación debido a caracteres de URL mal escapados.
- En el evento `success` envía a la consola el contenido de la variable `resp` y no una cadena de texto que pone `"resp"`.

Aquí tienes las modificaciones:

```
function formSubmit() {
  $('#formComi').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'phps/procesarcomisiones.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        'idusuario': $('#idusuario').val(),
        'fechadesde': $('#fechadesde').val(),
        'fechahasta': $('#fechahasta').val()
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        console.log('enviando datos');
      },
      success: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
      }
    });
  });
}
$(document).ready(formSubmit);
```

Comment: Gracias Oscar Garcia y mis disculpa por no furmular bien la pregunta primeravez que consulto aca en stackoverflow ..... gracias por la ayuda utilizare tu sugerencia ... y de nuevo gracias ....

Comment: De nada, no hay prisa. Si no te funciona o tienes dudas de cómo funciona algo dímelo.